# How to jump between Spaces on OS X when some are Fullscreen?

Tags: macos, spaces, fullscreen

How to jump between Spaces on OS X using some key + number?

I know I can jump between Desktops (not including fullscreen apps) using  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>[num]</kbd>  . I know I can jump between Spaces using  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>←</kbd>  /  <kbd>→</kbd> , but sometimes I want to jump from Desktop#1 to fullscreen app#5 and I want to be able to do this by pushing just one hotkey.

Can I do it on Mac OS somehow?
Or maybe you can advise me of some additional software to install to achieve such functionality?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm with @Tetsujin on this one. I never use fullscreen apps.

**However**, you could do what you want with [Total Spaces 2](http://totalspaces.binaryage.com/).

**Make sure to check the compatibility info below the download button**.

---

Let's say you use 3 fullscreen apps:

1. Close the full screen apps and create 3 extra spaces.
2. [Once you got those spaces, give them shortcuts **In Total Spaces 2.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6F2q.png)
3. Once the shortcuts are created, [remove the extra spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQ8mR.png)

   - Total Spaces will remember the shortcuts.
4. [Then add 3 new columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lC4H.png), but **don't press** the `add desktop` button.

   - This essentially reserves spots for the full screen apps

Comment: Nice one. I don't think it will persuade me to use fullscreen just yet - but good to know there's a workaround.

Comment: @Tetsujin The biggest reason I don't use it is because it isolates the app in its own space. I never understood that... I'd rather do that manually, if I feel that is something that I want. Luckily you can hide extra things in many applications and then just maximize the window.

Comment: My biggest reasons are the lack of shortcut key, which you've fixed for me above, but also that I have a pair of 27" screens, so 2 apps maxed on 2 screens feels far more useful than one on one screen [I also never use 'displays have separate spaces'. I got used to using Spaces long before the modern implementation, so prefer to stick to my old methods.]

Comment: @Tetsujin That is another weird thing about it. I really like that at least Photoshop and Illustrator have their own fullscreen modes, that circumvent all the OS bs. It just visually full screens the app, hiding dock and menu, but it stays in the same space. **You know...** Total Spaces has a feature that can "sync" all the spaces if you turn on the OS option "Displays have separate spaces". So basically all screens move to the same space number (if available), like they normally would.

Comment: Sounds good - but I think I'll stick with the method I've been using since... whenever it was introduced, Panther, Leopard...? Long time ago

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid it cannot be done natively.
The closest you can achieve is to jump the last regular desktop with  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>[num]</kbd>   then
 <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>→</kbd>  from there.

The difficulty is that fullscreen apps don't have a Space number, so you cannot add a shortcut key.

My personal solution is to simply never use fullscreen apps, I find them more trouble than they're worth.